# ¿Que es glob pattern y como se utiliza en programación en java?

Tags: java

Como se implementaría en el filtro de archivos en java. Que es Glob Pattern y como podría usar en código dentro de Java.

Comment: puede mirar esto igual ayuda -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming) o esto -> http://php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php para que se haga una idea. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente se usa la interfaz [PathMatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/PathMatcher.html) con metodo el metodo [getPathMatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher%28java.lang.String%29)

Aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo <s>[robado de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html)</s>

```
PathMatcher matcher =
    FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*.{java,class}");

Path filename = ...;
if (matcher.matches(filename)) {
    System.out.println(filename);
}
```

Claro que tambien podemos implementar el nuestro, pero para que agotarnos.